# Jekyll : Using datafiles with CSS

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I use Jekyll and I would like to use variable extract form a datafile into my css.
I would like to have something like that :

```
  .li{
      background : url({{data.image_link}});
  }
```

I use a for to browse all my data and display then into my html file. Every li will contain a different data with a different image.
Does it possible do that in a CSS file or it's only possible on the html file ?
Could you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems difficult AND overkill to do this in the CSS. This is something that works perfectly inline (in the layout). In the CSS you could/can set a fallback image.